# Additional moodle instance with Bitnami Moodle on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, moodle, bitnami

I have a Bitnami Moodle running on Google Virtual Machine. I would like to launch a new Moodle instance independent of the existing Moodle. I understand that the required steps for this would be to create a new database and then install new Moodle in a different folder. Is there a recommended way to achieve this or is a there any Bitnami script to do this? Are there any specific things that I need to take care before proceeding with this?

Thanks!